# Is there a shortcut command (maybe a flag) to checkout to a branch at the latest remote revision?

Tags: git

I am a code reviewer and person who merge branches to master. Often times the branches get updated and forced pushed and I need to be certain I am looking at the latest revision.

Currently I do:

```
git checkout master
git fetch --all --prune
git branch -D feature
git checkout feature
```

Is there a way to checkout to the lastest remote version of a branch in Git in one single command?

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch origin <branch> && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

It will be in detached HEAD state. But it doesn't matter in your case as long as you remember that it's pointing at the same commit as the branch in the remote repository does.